# Optional read from STDIN in C

Tags: c

My application is basically a shell which expects an input of type `cmd [x]`, where `cmd` is constant and `x` is optional. So `cmd 1` is legal as well as `cmd` by itself - then I assume a default parameter for `x`.

I am doing this:

```
char cmd[64];
scanf("%s", cmd);
int arg;
scanf("%d", &arg); // but this should be optional
```

How can I read the integer parameter, and set it to a default if none is currently available in the prompt? I do not want the prompt to wait for additional input if it was not given in the original command.

I tried several versions using `fgetc()` and `getchar()` and comparing them to `EOF` but to no avail. Each version I tried ends up waiting on that optional integer parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way:

```
   char b[73]; //powers of 2 magic is evil.
    if(fgets(b,sizeof b,stdin) != NULL) {
      char cmd[59]; //59, no command will ever be > 58. Ever I say.
      int arg;
      if(sscanf(b,"%58s %d",cmd,&arg) == 2) {
         //handle cmd and arg
      } else if(sscanf(b,"%58s",cmd) == 1) {
         //handle cmd only
      } else {
       // :-/
      }
    }
```

Comment: The second sscanf is unnecessary, if the first one returned 1, it had the same effect as the second sscanf.

Comment: If the first one returned 1, how do you absolutly, 100% sure , in every case,compiler,platform, know it didn't parse 'arg' ok, but barfed on 'cmd' ? Though 1 or 2 sccanfs - It's still very suboptimal, as you'd really want to report errors to the user if he gave 2 arguments, but the 2. could not be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, you can't. The C runtime takes input from the OS, but doesn't control it. To do something like this you will need to interact directly with the OS using platform specific APIs.

Comment: No, stdin does return EOF but only after it encounters an end-of-file (e.g. the user typed Ctrl-D, or whatever), otherwise it just sits there waiting for the user to type something.

Comment: That's what I meant... In the running context of an application it will never receive `EOF`, obviously, until terminated.

Comment: EOF is CTRL+D on Unix OS and CTRL+Z on Windows.

Comment: Ctrl-D (on POSIX at least) doesn't terminate an app - it marks end of file on standard input.

Comment: Offtopic: Heh! I just noticed you have 10 gold, 100 silver and 256 bronze badges... you have some nice round numbers!

Comment: @Juliano Well, 1000 bronze would b rounder, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading line-by-line? Can't you just read the whole command until you reach a "\n" (newline)? If you get two tokens before the newline, it is a command and the argument; if you read only one, it is the command only and you set the second argument to the default.

Comment: This is of course the correct solution - you really shouldn't be using scanf() for interactive input in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a program that works (sorry my previous answer was made in haste).

```
int main(){
    char cmd[100], line[100];
    int man = 0;
    printf("OK: ");
    fgets(line, 100, stdin);
    int num = sscanf(line,"%s %d",cmd,&man);
    if (num==1)printf("one! %s %d\n", cmd, man);
    else if (num==2)printf("two! %s %d\n", cmd, man);
}
```

fgets reads the line (with bounds checking), and sscanf will assess whether one or two tokens were entered.

Comment: mk. I tried before and it said "do you want to vote for it to be deleted?" which didn't make sense...
it's working now. thanks.